# How do I send key strokes to an open field in access table?

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, sendkeys

How do I send key strokes to an open field in access table? I have a tooling database with a table named "tbl_Tool_Number". In that table is a control named "View PDF". The control is suppose to hold a hyperlink. As I have entered data via an Excel spreadsheet, the hyperlink data has lost it's link field information. The control still "thinks" it is a hyperlink, but the actual link is not present in the "Address" field. The "Text to display" field does have the link text in it. I have to right click on the table control, Alt+H, Alt+T, Ctrl+C,Alt+E,Ctrl+V,Enter,Enter. There are over 250 records like this. I would like to enter the keys automatically.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw4K0.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. What does issuing those key combinations allow? What field type is this data in? Show sample data and desired output in your post.

Comment: You should explain what you want to do. There's probably a method to do it without sending the key strokes.